# How to make image selection area bigger in titanium App?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

How to increase selection area of any Label/image/button  everywhere in titanium App?

Because of Android device creates some problem while click on any Label/image/button. It takes time or sometime it requires double click to redirect to another page in App. I think this is just because it requires more touch area near by outside of any Label/image/button.

Please suggest your ideas.Thanks in advance

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Suppose below line i have added in xml file which show simple image with given height and weight, I have included onclick event in that but i also should click if i click somewhere outside area of image. How i can do it ?

<ImageView onClick="save_sign" borderColor="blue" borderWidth="1" left="15%" width="109" height="32" image="/images/login/accept.png" touchEnabled="true" />

Comment: Please edit your post with xml and JS file, so i can find some mistake

Comment: Do you want two different click on the same image? This is the goal?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to globally increase the tapeable area of every component in your app, I don't think that's possible to make in global way.

If it's hard for the user to tap some items, you'll have identify those items and give them a proper width and length. If you use Ti.UI.SIZE frequently, you will need to do the following:

- Wrap the item in a view and assign Ti.UI.SIZE as width or height
- Move the callback to the wrapping view
- Assign a size to bottom, top, left, and right of the item to make the wrapping view big enough to properly catch the user taps.